# Wordpress in a sub-directory

Tags: wordpress

Ok, so I set this up:

One wordpress site in the main folder so that is at domain.com and works fine.

The other is domain.com/ja now the main page works BUT for the pages e.g. domain.com/ja/about it redirects to domain.com/about

How can I solve this?

Comment: this link [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6393393/wordpress-subfolder-installation-redirecting-to-root)
can help you.

Answer (score 1):

It may problem with your .htaccess file.

Open your .htaccess file and change it.

```
    # BEGIN WordPress
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteBase /ja/

    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

    RewriteRule . /ja/index.php [L]

    </IfModule>

    # END WordPress
```

Answer (score 0):

A thought you modify your wp-config file?

```
define( 'PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/ja/' );
```